# Reference for Gerstenhaber algebra structure in a particular case

Tags: reference-request

I know it's true but I couldn't find a reference for the following statement:

*The exterior algebra of a Lie algebra is a Gerstenhaber algebra.*

Could you tell me a book/paper/something where I could read that?

Comment: Just check that there is a unique way of extending the bracket of the Lie algebra to the whole exterior algebra such that what you get is a Gerstenhaber algebra. It is an easy exercise.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you. In general, if I have defined a bracket at degree 1 and with that part I'm able to generate the whole algebra I can use the Leibnitz identity to extend the mentioned bracket.